# Are there differences in how quantum error correcting codes are applied on superconducting vs. trapped ion systems?

Tags: error-correction, superconducting-quantum-computing, trapped-ion

Are there any differences in how quantum error correcting codes are currently applied on superconducting vs. trapped ion systems?

Comment: Nothing is currently being applied as far as I know- we are presently in the “noisy, intermediate scale quantum” (NISQ) era sans error correction, and are not presently doing significant error correction for much of the present work. But another question could be “Are there any differences in how quantum error correcting codes *will be* applied on superconducting vs. trapped ion systems?” That may have some interesting answers, based on the topology of how the gates act on different qubits.